# Deleting stubborn items from my Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, trash, big-sur

I have a couple of items that are proving intractable to remove from my Mac. One is a no longer needed copy of the Catalina installer, the other is one set of the relocated items that macOS now puts at `/Users/Shared` with updates.

Trying to delete by putting in Trash & then emptying I get...

[image: alert 1 of 2]

For the Catalina installer, variously that error & ...

[image: alert 2 of 2]

For the relocated items folder.

Using terminal...

```
sudo rm -r /Users/username/Desktop/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app
```

results in the prompt...

```
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel restricted for /Users/username/Desktop/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg?
```

to which I respond `yes` & get...

```
rm: /Users/username/Desktop/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg: Operation not permitted
```

I get the same prompts & results for the files within the relocated items folder.

How can I get rid of these pesky items?

Update: I booted my Mac in recovery mode (& moved the Catalina installer to `/Users/Shared` for convenience) to try using Terminal there to delete these items. From there these items didn't even appear to be in `/Users/Shared`. Other files that I have at that location were also apparently absent. From that I wonder whether the new volume structure on macOS makes the location more complex than it appears in Finder.

Comment: As you correctly assumed, the location may be more complex in Recovery: if your volume is called "Macintosh HD", did you have a look in `ls -al "/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/Shared"`

Comment: @Redarm, I did not, but now you've suggested it,  I will.